# how to change textview's text dynamically when swiping the view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having a textview above the viewpager. i want to change the text of the textview while swiping the view pager.

**Below is exactly what is needed in my case:**

viewpager page1 ----> textview's text TEXT1

viewpager page2 ----> textview's text TEXT2

viewpager page3 ----> textview's text TEXT3

viewpager page4 ----> textview's text TEXT4

**when i am swiping back**

viewpager page4 ----> textview's text TEXT4

viewpager page3 ----> textview's text TEXT3

viewpager page2 ----> textview's text TEXT2

viewpager page1 ----> textview's text TEXT1

**Currently I am setting the text of the textview in below method:**

```
        @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mytextview.setText(TEXT1);
            return "TITLE1";
        case 1:
            mytextview.setText(TEXT2);
            return "TITLE2";
        case 2:
            mytextview.setText(TEXT3);
            return "TITLE3";
        case 3:
            mytextview.setText(TEXT4);
            return "TITLE4";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Using this method I am able to set the text of mytextview for page 2,3,4.
For page1 I am not able to set the text as shown in above method. Instead it is setting page2' textview text.

why this is happening? and anyone give the solution for this problem.
where should I set the textview's text(view is above view pager) when i am using the view pager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener();

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Karan's answer helped me a lot. I have added a bit more detail in an answer on a similar [multiple content in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21727183/959481)  question, where I've also been able to implement zoomable images with a TextView overlay. Hope the extra detail helps.